# ios - splitview in tab bar controller using storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app I want to use splitview inside the tab bar controller and the splitview controller will not be the `rootviewcontroller`. I use storyboards in my app and I can't find any clearly working example for this.

Firstly, I need to know it is possible or not.

If it is possible, how can I handle appdelegate to run splitview controller in tab bar controller?

I've also look `intelligentsplitviewcontroller` but it doesn't use storyboards.

Could anyone help me about this problem?